# cannot make post request in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, post

cannot men a POST request but cannot understand why, the struct is Codable and there is no erro in url.  I get this message error in console

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ac0dfea0 )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

but everything seems to be ok

my struct:

```
struct PostOfMine: Codable {
    let body: String?
    let id: Int?
    let title: String?
    let userId: Int?
}
```

my func:

```
func postData() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else {
        print("WARNING: url related error")
        return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let newPost = PostOfMine(body: "test body", id: 20, title: "test title", userId: 20)

    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newPost, options: [])
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (Data, _, error) in
    guard let data =  Data else {return}
    do {
        let sentPost = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        print(sentPost)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per apple documents:

**JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: [])**

If obj will not produce valid JSON, an exception is thrown. This exception is thrown prior to parsing and represents a programming error, not an internal error. You should check whether the input will produce valid JSON before calling this method by using isValidJSONObject(_:).

In your code exception is raised due to below reason

1. **JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: [])** 
   In this method you have to pass the valid JSON object e.g obj. You are just confirming to the **codable protocol** and passing the structure variable instead of JSON object.

**Code:**

```
struct PostOfMine: Codable {
    let body: String?
    let id: Int?
    let title: String?
    let userId: Int?

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case body
        case id
        case title
        case userId
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(body, forKey: .body)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(userId, forKey: .userId)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let newPost = PostOfMine(body: "test body", id: 20, title: "test title", userId: 20)
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let newPostData = try encoder.encode(newPost)
       //Send newPostData to your server.
        request.httpBody = newPostData
//Send data you your server


        //For Decoding the data use JSONDecoder
        let post = try JSONDecoder().decode(PostOfMine.self, from: newPostData)
        debugPrint(post)
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: so, this way, the potential php.file on server got the data? or there is something more to put where is         //Use newPostData ? if I try to print newPostData it gives me the bytes, is it so because is Data now. right? and, is //            request.httpBody = jsonBody not requested?

Comment: @biggreentree, You can send this newPostData to your server.
request.postData = newPostData

For retrieving the Data You have to use JSONDecoder.

Comment: if i put 'request.postData = newPostData' I get "Value of type 'URLRequest' has no member 'postData'"

Comment: @biggreentree,Use this request.httpBody = newPostData

I have updated my answer for your requirement please check it.

Comment: this seems to be workin! so the piece of code that really sends the "encoded" old newPost is             request.httpBody = newPostData, and the relative script on server should get it and use  it!

Comment: @biggreentree Happy to Help. Kindly upvote my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183880/discussion-between-hpm-and-biggreentree).

Answer (score 0):

Since your model conforms to `Codable` you get `JSONEncoder().encode(_:)` for free. Use that to encode instead of `JSONSerialization`

```
func postData() {

//...

//For this particular api, the server will take care of generating an `id` so leave that as `nil`

  let newPost = PostOfMine(body: "test body", id: nil, title: "test title", userId: 20)

    do { 
    let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newPost)

    } catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) { _, response, error in 

if error != nil { 
//check & handle error from upload task. 
} 

if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

 // Monitor the status code recieved from the server. 200-300 = OK
    print(response.statusCode)
 // prints 201 - Created

      }
  }.resume()

}
```